# Track Github composite action usage

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I've created composite actions which are being used in the other repositories. I would like to make track of my Github actions where they are being used currently, So I can be aware of breaking changes in any of the repositories because of the new changes in the composite action. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing those actions on a regular basis e.g. using nightly cron jobs? The inputs may be tested against incorrect values. The executables may be validated for their existence before use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need also a list of repositories that are using my composite actions within my organisation.

Comment: So, your actions are private and internal to your organization only?

Comment: Yes, they are internal and private.

Answer (score 2):

If you've enabled [Dependency Graph on both the action's repo as well as the consuming repo, GitHub should be able to tell you this](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/about-the-dependency-graph#dependency-graph-availability).

Here's an overview of one of my own composite actions and its dependencies.

[image: See dependents of a GitHub action through dependency graph]

Dependency Graph can be centrally enabled through the organization's policy:

[image: Enable dependency graph centrally from the organization settings]

Comment: Is there a REST API to list the deps? That would definitely be helpful for the OP's use case.

Comment: Not that I'm currently aware of. There probably is, but it's not documented.

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing. that was helpful :)

Comment: Hi @jessehouwing our composite action repo is public and the repo which is using the composite is internal. we have enabled dependency graph option on both of them but still it is not showing that our internal repo is using composite action in insights.